# linq to xml select sibling node of node that Node value starts with

Tags: linq-to-xml

I need to replicate a xsl statement where is selecting the sibling node of the node value starts with.

ex.

XSL statement

```
<xsl:value-of select="//FullProblemList/Test[starts-with(ReadCode, '13l')]/Notes"/>
```

linq statement

```
if (document.Descendants("FullProblemList").Descendants("Test").Descendants("ReadCode").First().Value.StartsWith("13l"))
            {
                this.lbl_patInfo_language.Text = document.Descendants("FullProblemList").Descendants("Test").Descendants("ReadCode").First().Value.StartsWith("13l").ToString();

            }
```

Comment: replicate as in copy/paste you above code? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I need to select with linq what the xsl statement is selecting.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
document.Descendants("FullProblemList")
        .Elements("Test")
        .Where(test => test.Element("RealCode").Value.StartsWith("13l"))
        .Select(test => test.Elements("Notes"));
```

It will give you an `IEnumerable<XElement>` that contains all the `Notes` elements for all the `Test` elements that have a `RealCode` element that starts with `13l`